# Is there a way to track delta changes for each plan per tab within a team in MS Teams?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get delta changes of a plan per tab within teams by making a API call.

*Get Delta for planner*

**URL GET** : [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/planner/all/delta](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Bid%7D/planner/all/delta)

I tried passing plan id in place of id in URL. This request returns a delta link to track changes.
After making some changes in a plan, I can able to track those changes using a delta URL.
But the problem here is the number of changes that we can track from a delta URL is limited.
When I tried this, I can able to track 32 recent changes only with that plan.
The other previous change details are not able to track with this delta URL.

Even I tried passing team id and user id in place of id in URL. Here also I found the same limited changes tracking issue and it returns the changes respect to all plans.
we don't get the details of the plan to which the particular changes are made.
And If I made some changes to a task item, we don't get the details of bucket or plan to which that task is associated to. These are some limitations I found regarding a Planner get delta query.

*Can someone please suggest a fix or workaround for this issue?*

*Is there a way to track delta changes for each plan per tab within a team in MS Teams ?
or Is there any other way you suggest me to try ?*

Answer (score 1):

Tracking changes within the scope of a plan is a feature we're currently working on, but it isn't available yet.

The delta mechanic requires the client to keep a cache of items, so that the client can know the associations and the final state of the changed item. Currently there are no plans to include info about buckets and plans with the delta.